# Javascript library for creating an interface like Ubuntu Unity or Gnome 3

Tags: javascript

Once I a came across a Javascript library which was great for creating an interface like Ubuntu Unity or Gnome Shell.
The demo consisted of some thumbnails with some tag (or something like that), and they could be filtered based on a criteria. Just like filtering the list applications in Unity (or Gnome Shell). It had a very nice effect too. Unfortunately I have forgotten the library name. :(

Does anyone know of something like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it! (after so much searching):
http://razorjack.net/quicksand/

Answer (score 1):

Filtering like this? http://www.filterplay.com

Comment: Something like this, but with much smoother effect.